# PDO bind data type and comparison

Tags: php, mysql

I have an integer column in a table and when I do a comparison the following code seems to work.

```
$myLimit = 10;
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE number<:myLimit");
$sth->bindParam(':myLimit',$myLimit); // default datatype is PDO::PARAM_STR
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Should I be using PDO::PARAM_INT for the third parameter for bindParam?
Also what about real numbers I can't use PDO::PARAM_INT for them as it will round them.

Comment: It will round for the integer column anyway. Question could be, why not to use `PDO::PARAM_INT`?

Comment: Why not use PARAM_INT and do a ceil() on your float value, so a 4.1 evals as 5, and is considered greater than 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number handling in PHP is notoriously bad. To pass big numbers around, my advice would be to keep them as strings.

**Edit** I've just tested the number handling; `PARAM_INT` works fine for large numeric strings, so you don't have to use `PARAM_INT` but there's no harm in being precise :)

As for floats, you should pass them using `PARAM_STR` to massively lose precision.